# Vue Js images are not copied to dist during build process

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a VueJs 3 project I have a list of PNG images. I put the PNG images under `src/assets/pngs/`. In my Vue componente I build the list with a For loop and put the image name in the img src. In dev mode this works fine.

```html
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <div class="card">
        <p class="hint">{{ item.name }}</p>
        <img :src="makeImgPath(item.img_name)" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
methods: {
  makeImgPath(imgName) {
    return '/src/assets/pngs/' + imgName + '.png';
  }
}
```

When I build the application with `npm run build` I get a 404 for all images in the list when built. I have also noticed that the pngs folder and therefore the images are not copied to dist/asstes/. Why is this so and what can I do so that the pictures are copied to the dist folder.
Thanks in advance, Max.

Comment: Static assets should be in `public` directory and referenced via absolute paths.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling

Answer (score 3):

yes, dynamic value image path's are not coping to dist folder in build process, I suggest to place move images into public folder and refer from it..